# CreateML App - Export trained mlmodel for use in app dev

Tags: ios, xcode, macos-catalina, createml, createmlui

Does anyone know how to export a trained mlmodel from Apple's Create ML App - the one that comes with XCode in Catalina

Answer (score 2):

When it has finished training it should appear on the right. Drag it out to the desktop. The only info I have found so far is in the videos. I think the one with the guy who has a beard. There's one presented by a woman, no beard, and then another with a guy who "integrates" the AIKit.

Comment: it seems to only export the differential transfer learning model and not the main model it is trained on? is there a way to have it also export the differential with main model such as mobilenet as well

Comment: I would love it to do this. It would be great to train again starting from where it finished. Also pause and continue and pause and export and continue. I have rummaged in the project file that you can open as a package but it does not save this.